# Is it possible to disable the minimize button of a window in javafx 2?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am doing a project in javafx. I already disabled the resizable property by using setResizable(false). Now I need to disable the minimize button too. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Initialize the style](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initStyle%28javafx.stage.StageStyle%29) of the stage to [UTILITY](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#UTILITY), then the stage won't have an enabled minimize button.

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

[image: utility]