# Periodically show my web-app's browser window (or JavaFX Window) on top of all other apps/windows on a user Desktop - any solution other than Cron?

Tags: java

I have a java application - preferably a web-application running in a Tomcat AppServer (either on a local machine or in the cloud - java hosting).

This application shall periodically show the user a message - so that some window appears on the screen (just pops up in the center of the screen like nagging advertisement), even if my app's window is minimized or inactive (lost focus). I can do such a pop-up with Java FX in the system tray - but I need a normal window (not just a small tray popup).

Here is the problem - when my app's browser window is not active (lost focus or minified) I don't know how to bring it to the front of all other open windows and applications.

I can make some Java FX Desktop module to periodically (on timer) enable my web-app browser-window to pop up. Or I can even make the whole app in Java FX (a small Java FX utility + web app would be better though) - but I don't see how I can do it in java FX either.

I can periodically start my app with Cron to achieve this, but is there any app-programming way to do it?

My own research:

I guess *there is no javascript way to do it* - because the browser would isolate my web-page code from the rest of the system and won't let me interfere with more than my own web-page.

I also found that *I can build a Desktop app using* [Electron framework](https://electronjs.org/) and it looks like (at first glance) it supports what I need. [Wiki on Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)).

Also I can write a Desktop app in Java using [Qt-Wrapper library for java (Qt Jambi)](https://github.com/qtjambi/qtjambi) - it is good to know I can use Qt from Java.

If I understood right, it [seems possible in iOS/Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660129/app-window-on-top-of-all-windows-including-others-app-windows) and [maybe possible in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236914/impossible-to-set-the-window-on-top-of-the-top-of-the-top-window)

But I need a java solution anyway. 
Or java + some very "thin" launcher in any other language. 
Maybe some activation-scheduler in some scripting language?

As to JavaFX I have tried:

- stage.setMaximized(true);
- stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
- stage.setFocused(true);
- stage.toFront();
- nonPrimaryStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

CRON-like: Scheduling program start-up for Windows 10:

- [Z-Cron](https://www.z-cron.com/freeware.html)
- Win_Button + R, type `taskschd.msc` - Windows Task Scheduler
- `schtasks` command in Console
- [List of many other Win10 Task_Scheduling Tools](https://thegeekpage.com/task-schedulers-for-windows-10/)

Comment: Have you considered using the browser's Desktop Notifications API?

https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Comment: Try this [Wumpus example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320014/how-to-call-launch-more-than-once-in-java), which is a JavaFX app that periodically shows and is set to be [always on top](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setAlwaysOnTop-boolean-).

Comment: @jewelsea It is fine, thank you! But when the user manually minimizes app's window, the app never shows up itself on timer - until the user manually clicks it on the Windows taskbar again...

Comment: [Remove the minimize button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965855/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-minimize-button-of-a-window-in-javafx-2).